# Is there a blaze spawning Y requirement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The wiki for minecraft does not have a height requirement but when I try to spawn blazes at Y=26 then nothing happens but when I do exactly the same at Y=65 it works fine.

I made my two tests in a similar way. Just a simple platform almost two high (trapdoor on top to prevent pigmen). Then I walk away 24 blocks and look at the platform.

The only major difference is that the one at y=26 cuts through a nether fortress pillar, and the one at Y=65 is on top of the fortress.

The map I use is skyblock 4, at position X=-80 Z=80 chunk. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: There is something special about spawning on intersections (or where intersections used to be, if you mined out the blocks) and the rest of the fortress. They might only spawn at or near intersections, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the fortress bounding box just didn't go down below 46.

I downloaded a bounding box mod and could see the spawn areas.